# Large classification dataset

Tags: classification

I am very curious about a very large classification dataset approx. 1e9 samples and 1e4 classes. However, I cannot find any. Could you recommend me some?

Answer (score 2):

1B rows is easy to reach.  10K labels can be achieved with concatenations.

For example, take Wikipedia for 100 languages, and split it into rows - by sentence, by n-gram

You now have enough rows, but still only 100 labels.

Then run some lib over each, and concatenate the output to the labels, yielding a new set of labels.

The lib could be a parsing lib like spaCy (POS tag sequence), it could be the language identification like [langid.py](https://github.com/saffsd/langid.py), it could be sentiment, or combinations of the above.  But somehow there should also be ~100 possible outputs (100^2 == 10^4).

For example you might have a row from the 3-gram `va a Milano` from the Corsican Wikipedia (`co`).  For that sequence langid.py returns `[['es': 0.5, 'it': 0.4, ...]`.  So the generated row can be:

`va a Milano \t co_es_it`

Note the classes will not be balanced, although you could balance them by doing it at greater scale and then discarding as needed.